# How to disable programs at windows startup

Tags: windows-10

I opened task manager in windows-10.
There is a startup tab and disabled some programs. Still I see many programs running and consuming lot of memory.
Is there any other place I should disable the unnecessary programs which start automatically

Comment: You have to restart for that setting to take effect.

Comment: There is usually no need to stop needed programs from starting to conserve memory. If your total memory used is 4 or so GB at idle, there is nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: Google Autoruns by Sysinternals.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for such actions to be of use, you need to restart your PC. But nonetheless, there is somewhere else you can look: Press Win+R to open the RUN dialogue and enter

```
shell:startup
```

and it will take you to a folder in which multiple links are located which will be opened on startup. Sometimes there are things listed here that are not displayed by the task manager. In addition, there is also

```
shell:Common Startup
```

which is of the same kind, it only shows processes that start independant of the user who logs in.

I hope this helped, if something is unclear please just ask.